# How to use ax.get_ylim() in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I do the following imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes as ax
import matplotlib
import pylab
```

It properly executes

```
plt.plot(y1, 'b')
plt.plot(y2, 'r')
plt.grid()
plt.axhline(1, color='black', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

and shows the graph.

But if I insert

```
print("ylim=", ax.get_ylim())
```

I get the error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_ylim'

I have tried replacing ax. with plt., matplotlib, etc., and I get the same error.

What is the proper way to call `get_ylim`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not import `matplotlib.axes`,  in your example the only import you need is `matplotlib.pyplot`

`get_ylim()` is a method of the matplotlib.axes.Axes `class`. This class is always created if you plot something with pyplot. It represents the coordinate system and has all the methods to plot something into it and configure it.

In your example, you have no Axes  called ax, you named the matplotlib.axes module ax.

To get the axes currently  used by matplotlib use `plt.gca().get_ylim()`

or you could do something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) # 1 Row, 1 Column and the first axes in this grid

ax.plot(y1, 'b')
ax.plot(y2, 'r')
ax.grid()
ax.axhline(1, color='black', lw=2)

print("ylim:" ax.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

If you just want to use the pyplot API: `plt.ylim()` also returns the ylim.

Comment: +1 precisely. It is unnecessary to import `matplotlib.axes` if you're going to use `pyplot` or `pylab`. If you want to get an `Axes` object easily, use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Comment: Even shorter would be `plt.plot(y1)` `print(plt.gca().get_ylim())`. No need for any ax.

Comment: This is in the text ;)